# Some APIs that support the NT namespace absolute path of the format "\Device\Xxx"

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, device, device-driver

In this document,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#paths

> To make these device objects accessible by Windows applications, the device drivers create a symbolic link (symlink) in the Win32 namespace, "Global??", to their respective device objects. For example, COM0 and COM1 under the "Global??" subdirectory are simply symlinks to Serial0 and Serial1, "C:" is a symlink to HarddiskVolume1, "Physicaldrive0" is a symlink to DR0, and so on. Without a symlink, a specified device "Xxx" will not be available to any Windows application using Win32 namespace conventions as described previously. **However, a handle could be opened to that device using any APIs that support the NT namespace absolute path of the format "\Device\Xxx".**

What are the APIs? Let me know some such functions please.

---

For example, we can have a device sitting in the `GLOBAL??` namespace:

```
GLOBAL??\
   COM227
```

This device we can successfully open using `CreateFile`:

```
//Note: we have to prefix it with \\.\ in order to tell CreateFile that
//we want to open something from the Global device namespace.
//Otherwise it will try to open a file
HANDLE hdev = CreateFile("\\.\COM227", GENERIC_READ, 0, null, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if (hdev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   raise new EWin32Exception(GetLastError);
```

This device (along with every other device in the Win32 **Global??** namespace), actually a symbolic link to the *"real"* device:

```
GLOBAL??\
   COM227 (SymbolicLink) ==> \Device\VCP0
Device\
   VCP0  (Device)
```

So we try to open this **real** device:

```
HANDLE hdev = CreateFile("\\.\Device\VCP0", GENERIC_READ, 0, null, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if (hdev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   raise new EWin32Exception(GetLastError);
```

But it fails with error code 3 (The system cannot find the specified file).

Short:

- **Works**: `COM227` (which is an alias of `\Device\VCP0`)
- **Fails**: `\Device\VCP0`

The problem is that

- [@paulsm4 says that `CreateFile` **should** work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546261/some-apis-that-support-the-nt-namespace-absolute-path-of-the-format-device-xxx/3549048#3549048)
- @larryostermm agrees, and even gives the device path syntax (*e.g.* `\Device\Xxx`)
- except that it **doesn't** work

Which means that `CreateFile` is **not** one of the *"APIs that support the NT namespace absolute path format of \Device\Xxx"*.

> However, a handle could be opened to that device using any APIs that support the NT namespace absolute path of the format "\Device\Xxx".

What **are** the APIs?

Comment: Please consider changing your accepted answer. The answer by @Robert is the correct one. You can only access a restricted subset of devices via the `\\.\ ` prefix via the Win32 API's; API's that in particular do **not** support the NT namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benjamin -

1. The simple fact is that you CAN open a "special device file" in Windows, very much as you do in *nix.  This is what I tried to say in my original reply. I stand by everything I said in my first post.  And I believe the MSDN link I referred to there does a very good job of explaining this, too.
2. The syntax for a *nix device file is "/dev/SOME_DEVICE".  Multiple devices are (by convention, not necessity) distinguished as "/dev/SOME_DEVICE0", "/dev/SOME_DEVICE1", etc.  Device files can also be "aliased" using *nix "symbolic links".
3. The syntax for a Windows device file is a UNC name.
   I'm sure you're familiar with UNC shares (for example, "\\myserver\c$").
   In all the examples we've discussed above, the server happens to be the local host.  Hence "\\.\SOME_RESOURCE_NAME".

It's really as simple as that.

And it DOES work.

Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Thank you in advance .. PSM

Comment: Thanks paulsm & Larry. I misunderstood the sentences in MSDN.

Answer (score 6):

The answers provided so far are misleading at best.  They do not answer your question or cover the important distinction between the NT namespace and the other namespaces.

When accessing the NT namespace you need to use the API calls that start with Nt, such as NtOpenFile, if you want to access devices that are only found in the NT namespace of the kernel.  For example, a device in \Devices with no symbolic link in \GLOBAL??.

The other calls mentioned above work fine if you are accessing the Win32 device namespace but these require the driver to create a symbolic link in that namespace.

If you want to access a device that is only found in the NT namespace then use [NtOpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432381(v=vs.85).aspx). This is really a very old API call and has drifted in and out of the userpace header files.  It is available again and works just fine.

Comment: This is the only correct answer to the question. You can use the normal Win32 API with the prefix `\\.\ ` to open any device whose name is published in `\GLOBAL??`, but this is only a restricted set of the devices, as the driver itself has to publish the device in the way described here.

Comment: "a device in \Devices with no symbolic link in \GLOBAL??" - but \GLOBAL?? has symlink to globalroot, does not it?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of treating a "device" as a "file" is common in *nix (Unix, Linux, Mac OS, etc).

Basically, the MSDN article means that *any* Win32 API that opens a "file" (either a local disk file, or a UNC resource) could just as easily open a "special device".

A couple of examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
  CreateFile
  WriteFile
  ReadFile
  CloseHandle
```

Comment: CreateFileW(L"\\Device\\Xxx", ...) Is it possible? I don't think so.
It must be a symbolic lick in GLOBAL?? namespace.

Comment: Look at the MSDN link I cited - I believe you'll find an example!

Remember: "CreateFile()" is really pretty much a synonym for "open resource".  It doesn't necessarily imply you're creating that resource from scratch.

Comment: But you do need to use a different syntax: \\.\device\Xxx.

Comment: @Larry It doesn't work. I can't open any device by the syntax. Does it work really?

Comment: Did you read the "Win32 Device Namespaces" part of the article you linked?  Where did you get the device name you mentioned above?

Comment: What I said is, "\\.\C:" works but "\\.\Device\HarddiskVolume1" doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use the native API in order to open something in the \Device directory of the object manager namespace (Win32 restricts you to a subset of the namespace).

Comment: @snoone: What subset might that be?